# Make input="text" field required if checkbox was selected

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

i have a bootstrap formular which include two different addresses

The first address is the main address of the user and all fields are required.

The second address is the billing address and this field (street, street number, zip code and city) should be required if the user select the "billing address checkbox".

I work with http://formvalidation.io/ but i don't know how to get the dependence between checkbox and my billing address input fields.

Maybe someone can help?

Comment: You can take a look here maybe it will help you http://formvalidation.io/examples/conditional-validation/

Answer (score 8):

You can add a jQuery `.change()` event listener to the checkbox which then toggles the `required` attribute on the text input:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

        if ($('input[type="text"]').attr('required')) {
            $('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('required');
        } 

        else {
            $('input[type="text"]').attr('required','required');
        }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<p><input type="checkbox" /> Check Me to make the Text Box a Required Field</p>
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

Here is the same approach in native javascript so that you can compare and contrast against the jQuery:

```js
var checkBox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
var textInput = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

function toggleRequired() {

    if (textInput.hasAttribute('required') !== true) {
        textInput.setAttribute('required','required');
    }

    else {
        textInput.removeAttribute('required');  
    }
}

checkBox.addEventListener('change',toggleRequired,false);
```

```html
<form>
<p><input type="checkbox" />Check Me to make the Text Box a Required Field</p>
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also check if the checkbox is actually checked rather than when it is clicked. It will work better for scenarios where you use already checked fields.

```
let toggleInputRequired = ( checkbox, input ) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', e => {
        if ( e.currentTarget.checked )
            input.setAttribute( 'required', 'required' );
        else
            input.removeAttribute( 'required' );
    } );

    checkbox.onchange();
}

toggleInputRequired( document.querySelector( 'input[name="checkbox_name"]' ), document.querySelector( 'input[name="input_text"]' ) );
```

Comment: what is for checkbox.onchange();?